# How to specify Response class and return Status Codes using Swagger/ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger

Is it possible with `ServiceStack.Api.Swagger v3.9.33` to describe the response of an API operation and the returned status codes using `Swagger`? Perhaps by attribute decoration on the Response class/properties, etc.

Like the highlighted sections for the following example operation from the pet store API:
(http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/)

[image]

I can only see the HTTP methods and Request DTOS can be decorated on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API and quick glance at code looks like may not yet be supported, https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, it's possible if you pull the head of the ServiceStack repo. I just got a pull request merged that adds the option to decorate your request DTOs with an [ApiResponse] attribute. See here for details:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/590#issuecomment-17575292

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is gone :( i have the ApiResponse attribute but just to add StatusCodes. When i check the json the ResponseClass Model is there but has no properties even though i have it attributed with Api & ApiMember

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your Request (where you have applied the RouteAttribute) to implement `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturn<TResponseType>` where TResponseType is your response type.

So the example should look something like:

```
[Route("/todos")]
[Route("/todos/{Ids}")]
public class Todos : IReturn<List<Todo>>
```

`IReturn<List<Todo>>` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently searching for a solution to the same problem.

I've come to the finding, that it's currently not implemented
--> see: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs for proof

So, currently there is no integration of the response Models or Status Codes.

Comment: Yes, I assumed no response in a few months meant no progress yet, hopefully on the roadmap. Cheers.

Comment: If you have some spare hours, I briefly looked into it:
sample: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs.json/pet

docs: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Resource-Listing

I would suggest: walking through all the response classes (in the same way as service stack does with the requests) and scan the Attributes (you would have to specify them to)
--> but that part is to much for my c#/.net knowledge

Comment: the corresponding github-ticket: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/590